# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar los saltos de línea de CRLF a LF en SSIS?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

Un proveedor me envía varios archivos que cargo en una tabla de una base de datos MSSQL que tienen el tipo de salto de línea en CRLF, eventualmente estos archivos me vienen con otro tipo de salto (LF).

Podría solicitarle que uniformize el tipo de salto de línea, pero me dio curiosidad saber como podría evaluar que tipo de salto de línea me viene y según eso carga la información con un data flow task diferente, teniendo en cuenta que el tipo de salto de línea de la primera línea por archivo será siempre el mismo para las líneas siguientes.

O en su defecto lo que dice el título, cambiar el tipo de salto de línea por completo como si se tratase de un replace.

Answer (score 2):

No creo que debas remplazar el fin de linea o algo así, mejor seria que la parte de tu código que separa el archivo en lineas se encargue de manejar los dos estilos de fin de linea.

Si el archivo lo tienes en el disco, es muy fácil, con [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.100).aspx). No habrá diferencia para ti si el archivo viene con CRLF o LF.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"ruta\al\archivo.txt");
```

Ahora, suponiendo que lees todo el archivo en una variable string, podrías dividirlo primero en lineas separadas sin importar el salto de linea usando [`string.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"ruta\al\archivo.txt", Encoding.Default))
{
    string fileText = sr.ReadToEnd();
    string[] lines = fileText.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" },
                                             StringSplitOptions.None);
}
```

Pero, Si realmente necesitas remplazarlos por "\n", puedes agregar lo siguiente luego de cualquiera de los métodos anteriores:

```
String nuevoArchivoConLF = String.Join("\n", lines);
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, ahora llego a comprender perfectamente la correlación entre CRLF y \r\n, no sabía que era esa, por otro lado, cargo los archivos por medio de un Flat File Connection Manager, pero esa correlación me ayudó a validar cuando un archivo viene con uno otro tipo de salto de linea, te daré un +1, y colocaré mi propia respuesta. gracias nuevamente.